# Как преобразовать данные из numeric в дату в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

В MS SQL 2016 создано представление, из которого надо забирать данные. Одно из полей [AuditRecordCreationDate] должно содержать дату, но SSMS говорит, что его формат: AuditRecordCreationDate (numeric(19,0) Не Null)  и данные в нем выглядят как 1526628000258

Как правильно преобразовать его в формат даты, чтобы забирать запросом и передавать в другую систему?

P.S. Пробовал разные варианты - разные ошибки:

`cast(AuditRecordCreationDate as datetime) as NEWDATE,`

*Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.*

`cast(cast(AuditRecordCreationDate as nvarchar(40)) as datetime) as NEWDATE,`

*Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1526628000258 / 1000, '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000');
-- или даже
SELECT DATEADD(millisecond, 1526628000258 % 1000,DATEADD(second, 1526628000258 / 1000, '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000'));
-- или уж совсем
SELECT DATEADD(millisecond, 1526628000258 % 1000, CAST(DATEADD(second, 1526628000258 / 1000, '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000') AS DATETIME2));
```

Во втором запросе получается 257 миллисекунд, а не 258 - но это не ко мне претензии...

Напрямую миллисекунды прибавить низзя - второй параметр должен помещаться в INT.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=af7abd9cb7e5132aaaef4c6dcd2e6208)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как я понял исходные цифры это unixtimestamp, только в конце миллисекунды добавлены, поэтому на 1000 надо делить, верно? А можно ли сразу выводить в формате без милисекунд? И время надо именно от 01:00:00 отсчитывать или же от 00:00:00 ?

Comment: И еще хотел спросить а как понять или определить в запросе в каком часовом поясе время? Например, исходное значение 1590647469413

после применения `cast(DATEADD(second, AuditRecordCreationDate / 1000,  '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0') as smalldatetime) as NEWDATE` получаю 2020-05-28 06:31:00, но это явно время по UTC, потому что на сервере с базой time zone MSK

Comment: @fr0sty *Как я понял исходные цифры это unixtimestamp* Да. *в конце миллисекунды добавлены, поэтому на 1000 надо делить, верно?* Да. *время надо именно от 01:00:00 отсчитывать или же от 00:00:00 ?* Строго как написано. См. описание типа данных, минимальное значение. *как понять или определить в запросе в каком часовом поясе время?* Никак - этой информации нет в данных. Только на основании сведений о настройках времени там, где эти данные сформированы.